# Linux kernel scheduling

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling

I wish to know how Old Linux scheduling algorithm SJF (shortest job first) calculates the process runtime ?

Comment: Fair enough question, but are you sure that Linux ever used a SJF scheduler?

Comment: @zdav: I'm pretty sure early versions of Linux 2.0 had an experimental SJF scheduler, which was very short lived. It would go back to Redhat 4, about circa 1996/1997 or so. IIRC, only people who hand rolled Linux with GNU were really testing it, RH did not ship with it. ICBW, it was a loooong time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem actually is one of the major reasons why it is rarely used in common environments, since SJF algorithm requires accurate estimate of the runtime of all processes, which is only given in specialized environments.

In common situations you can only get estimated and inaccurate length of process running time, for example, by recording the length of previous CPU bursts of the same process, and use mathematical approximation methods to calculate how long it will run next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some bandwidth to burn, you *might* be able to find the actual code [here](http://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.0/). Start at 2.0, where I think you'll find it as experimental.

SJF was (IIRC) **extremely** short lived, for the exact [reasons that ZelluX noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406860/linux-kernel-scheduling/2407026#2407026).

I think your only hope to understand the method behind its madness lives in the code at this point. You *may* be able to build it and get it to boot in a simulator.

**Edit:**

I'm now not completely sure if it ever **did** go into mainline. If you can't find it, don't blame me :)